# How can I capture the changes made to a data.frame in dplyr::select?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, tidyselect

I would like to create a subclass of `data.frame` that carries around some information about the state of particular columns. I thought the best way to do this would be with an attribute, `special_col`. A simple constructor seems to work fine:

```r
# Light class that keeps an attribute about a particular special column
new_my_class <- function(x, special_col) {
  stopifnot(inherits(x, "data.frame"))
  attr(x, "special_col") <- special_col
  class(x) <- c("my_class", class(x))
  x
}

my_mtcars <- new_my_class(mtcars, "mpg")
class(my_mtcars) # subclass of data.frame
#> [1] "my_class"   "data.frame"
attributes(my_mtcars)$special_col # special_col attribute is still there
#> $special_col
#> [1] "mpg"
```

However, I run into the problem that I need to write methods for various generics to update this attribute if the column name happens to change. As shown below, using the `data.frame` method will leave the attribute untouched.

```r
library(dplyr)
# Using select to rename a column does not update the attribute
select(my_mtcars, x = mpg) %>%
  attr("special_col")
#> [1] "mpg"
```

Here is my current, naive attempt at a method for `my_class`. I go about capturing the dots and then parsing them to figure out which columns were renamed, and changing the attribute if they were in fact renamed.

```r
# I attempt to capture the dots supplied to select and replace the attribute
select.my_class <- function(.data, ...) {
  exprs <- enquos(...)
  sel <- NextMethod("select", .data)
  replace_renamed_cols(sel, "special_col", exprs)
}
# This is slightly more complex than needed here in case there is more than one special_col
replace_renamed_cols <- function(x, which, exprs) {
  att <- attr(x, which)
  renamed <- nzchar(names(exprs)) # Bool: was column renamed?
  old_names <- purrr::map_chr(exprs, rlang::as_name)[renamed]
  new_names <- names(exprs)[renamed]
  att_rn_idx <- match(att, old_names) # Which attribute columns were renamed?
  att[att_rn_idx] <- new_names[att_rn_idx]
  attr(x, which) <- att
  x
}
# This solves the immmediate problem:
select(my_mtcars, x = mpg) %>%
  attr("special_col")
#> [1] "x"
```

Unfortunately, I think this is particularly brittle and fails in other circumstances, as shown below.

```r
# However, this fails with other expressions:
select(my_mtcars, -cyl)
#> Error: Can't convert a call to a string
select(my_mtcars, starts_with("c"))
#> Error: Can't convert a call to a string
```

My feeling is that it would be preferable to get the changes in columns after `tidyselect` has done its work, rather than attempting to generate the same changes in the attributes from capturing dots as I have done. The key question is: **how can I use `tidyselect` tools to understand what changes are going to happen to a dataframe when select variables?**. Ideally I could return something that keeps track of which columns are renamed to which others, which are dropped etc. and use that to keep the attribute `special_col` up to date.

Comment: I see that might help? I don't really want to translate to `data.table` code, but I'll look at the source of that and see how it does the capturing before the translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to do it is to encode you attribute updating in the `[` and `names<-` methods, then the default select method should use these generics. This should be the case in the next major version of dplyr.

See https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/blob/8d1c76dae81eb55032bcbd83d2d19625db887025/R/eval-select.R#L152-L156 for a preview of what select.default will look like. We might even remove tbl-df and data.frame methods from dplyr. The last line is of interest, it invokes `[` and `names<-` methods.

Comment: You might run into issues because we've only recently started to make our default methods generics. Please report non-generic default methods as bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the preview into thoughts on this! I do need to figure out the best way to go about the `[` and `names<-` methods. However, doesn't this approach make sense mostly when my subclass does not inherit from `data.frame`, since at present I can use `NextMethod()` to do the actual subsetting? or are you saying that `select` will end up using `[` and `names<-` everywhere

Comment: I think `select()` will use `[` and `names<-` in the default and data frame methods (which might end up being merged).